# In iOS does realm support deleting a row in a tableview with animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

For example this is the following code I have regarding deleting a tableview row.

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.array = [Note allObjects];
        RLMRealm *realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm;
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.array[indexPath.row]);
        [realm deleteObject:self.array[indexPath.row]];
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    }
}
```

Although I get the initial result I want of deleting the row it unfortunately has no animation so the abrupt update of the tableview just doesn't look good. I understand that normally this is the actual method to use achieve the animation in a tableview
`[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

By the way this is the closest thing I found regarding my question but it just doesn't work for me. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1045

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Do you update your UI somewhere with a notification block? ->

```
// Observe Realm Notifications
self.token = [realm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, RLMRealm * realm) {
  [myViewController updateUI];
}];
```

If yes, then you first have to animate the deletion and then remove the object from realm:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [self deleteItemAtIndexPath: indexPath];
  }
}

- (void)deleteItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // Delete the row from the data source
  self.array = [Note allObjects];
  RLMRealm *realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm;
  [realm beginWriteTransaction];
  NSLog(@"%@",self.array[indexPath.row]);
  [realm deleteObject:self.array[indexPath.row]];
  [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

Anyway. Just animate your row first and then delete the data from your Array/Realm :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: This comment was helpful but I ultimately found this resource in Swift: 
https://realm.io/news/marin-todorov-fine-grained-notifications/

Comment: The Realm Api did not offer that kind of functionality when I proposed my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it in Swift and Realm v1.0.0

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        deleteRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}

private func deleteRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let objectToDelete = objects[indexPath.row]
    do {
        try realm.write() {
            realm.delete(objectToDelete)
        }
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } catch {
        print("Could not delete site")
    }
}
```